# Split a node module library into individual files with Webpack and NextJS

Tags: webpack, next.js

I have a library from `node_modules` that I am dynamically importing to avoid a large initial transfer size, and to reduce unused code. However, when I inspect the webpack output with the bundle analyzer, parts of the library are still bundled in the initial file.

Here, `codemirror` (unneeded) is bundled with `next` (needed).

[image]

How can I exclude `codemirror` from the initial bundle, and also split each `codemirror/mode/**/**.js` into separate and individual files with Webpack (not all languages are needed).

One config that I've tried already in `next.config.js` is

```js
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.assetsChunk = {
        chunks: 'all',
        maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
        minSize: 0,
        name: 'codemirror',
        priority: 10,
        test: /[\\\/]node_modules\/codemirror[\\\/]/,
      };
    }
```

However, `codemirror` is still not excluded, and it bundles all `codemirror/modes/**/**.js` files into a single file.

Comment: I'm facing the similar problem, how did you solve @Sentient?

Comment: I have not managed to solve it :(